# starting geoserver programmatically using java

Tags: geoserver

I'm looking to run some integration tests with multiple geoserver instances and thought the best way would be to do setup and teardown programmatically.

Are there any simple examples of how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could start geoserver inside tomcat using {tomcat_home}/bin/startup.sh from command line (almost all programming languages let you run OS commands).

Now, for setup and data connections, your best chance is use Geoserver Rest API:
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/

If you want to replicate a same configuration/data setup for multiple geoserver instances, you could create a ready "data" directory with all your configurations and paste that directory on every geoserver instance you want.

The teardown step you can use {tomcat_home}/bin.shutdown.sh command.